# I am trying to send the selectedArray from selectTheMode component to Game component, but it is not showing up in the game component

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const SelectTheMode = () => {
  const [selectedArray, setSelectedArray] = useState("");
  const [tabIndexSelected, setTabIndexSelected] = useState(false);

  const handleDivClick = (arrayName) => {
    setSelectedArray(arrayName);
    setTabIndexSelected(true);
  };

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    console.log(selectedArray);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <h1>Выбери режим игры</h1>
      </header>
      <div onClick={() => handleDivClick("Array1")} tabIndex="1" className='ModeContainer'>
        <h1></h1>
        <h2>Базовый</h2>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h4>
      </div>        
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SelectTheMode;
```

```js
import React from 'react'

const Game = ({selectedArray}) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{selectedArray}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default Game;
```

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';
import AddTeams from './Pages/AddTeams';
import SelectTheMode from './Pages/SelectTheMode';
import Game from './Pages/Game';

function App() {
  const [selectedArray, setSelectedArray] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <SelectTheMode setSelectedArray={setSelectedArray}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/teams" component={AddTeams}/>
        <Route path="/game">
          <Game selectedArray={selectedArray}/>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I put the  in the selectTheMode component and it kinda worked but it showed the selectedArray in selectTheMode component not in the Game component

Answer (score 0):

This involves the mutual communication mechanism between react components. When you want to change the state of the parent component through the child component, you should pass the method of the parent component to the child component to call, like this:

```js
const SelectTheMode = ({setSelectedArray}) => {
  // setSelectedArray methon form parent
  const [tabIndexSelected, setTabIndexSelected] = useState(false);

  const handleDivClick = (arrayName) => {
    setSelectedArray(arrayName);
    setTabIndexSelected(true);
  };

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    console.log(selectedArray);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <h1>Выбери режим игры</h1>
      </header>
      <div onClick={() => handleDivClick("Array1")} tabIndex="1" className='ModeContainer'>
        <h1></h1>
        <h2>Базовый</h2>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h4>
      </div>        
    </div>
  )
}

export default SelectTheMode;
```